# Escaping Characters in Email with PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, email, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm having a problem figuring out the logic behind how characters are being escaped when I use the `mail()` function for PHP.  I'm using PHP 5.2, with magic_quotes_qpc ON and runtime/sybase OFF.  Here's the problem.

1. A have a form that takes a text input and I use `mysqli_real_escape` to escape special characters for use in an SQL statement like such:

   ```
   $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['text']);
   ```
2. If I type the following comment "I wouldn't eat that!" into the form, I see the following in database - "I wouldn\'t eat that!", which is what I would expect.  If I add carriage returns/new lines all I see in the database field in phpMyAdmin is the carriage return and newline with no special characters (i.e. no "\r\n" or anything like that).
3. When I use the `mail` function to send a message (i.e. `mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers)`) I have been getting something weird like this in the email body:

   ```
   I wouldn\\\'t eat that\r\nI couldn\\\'t eat that
   ```

At the end of the day I just want the email output to be formatted exactly like the form input, in other words:

```
I wouldn't eat that
I couldn't eat that
```

I'm not sure why there is a triple escape before the apostrophe and why the \r\n is showing up in my email.

Answer (score 2):

Magic quotes are bad. Don't use them.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php

If you're using magic quote *and* mysqli_real_escape_string, then that explains why the strings are doubly escaped.

```
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['text']); // $_GET['text'] is already escaped

...

mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers); // Now $text contains a doubly escaped string
```

Turn off magic quotes (ensure you're app can handle that) and only escape when inserting into database (if using parameterized queries, i.e., PDO or mysqli, no need to **ever** escape!).

As a last resort, you can try using [stripslashes](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on the string.

Comment: Webbiedave - Thanks for the great advice.  I turned off magic_quotes and confirmed it's off with phpinfo.  I know it's off because I now get errors when I try to enter apostrophes into the form without using mysqli_real_escape_string.  I tried to print my message again and I'm still seeing escaped apostrophes and the newline/carriage returns symbols (body email is still = "I wouldn\'t eat that\r\n\r\nI couldn\'t eat that\r\n\r\n").  Do I need to transform the message on the way out of the database still?

Comment: You can do a simple `$output = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n", $output);`. Although it might not be the best way, it will work.

Comment: minitech - interesting that you made that recommendation because I something similar elsewhere on the web.  I also tried it and it worked.  My question is WHY do you have to do that?  Is the \r\n command getting double escaped when it goes through the mail function?  Not clear to me what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving results from the MySQL database, you need to use `stripslashes()` on the output or they will still contain the escaping slashes, for some reason.

Edit:

Then, you can do `$theOutput = str_replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n", $theOutput);` to fix the newlines.

Comment: No, you don't need that. That's a bad practice that stems from confusion with using magic_quotes and real escaping at the same time. You need to be exact with inserting data into the DB, not trying to clean it up afterwards. Correctly inserted data will come back from the database as intended.

Comment: I don't have magic quotes turned on and I still need to do this.

Comment: Then there might be something else wrong with your setup or database function usage.

Comment: minitech and mario - thanks for your help.  please see my updated comment above.